# Can artifacts gain levels and if so, how?

Tags: borderlands

I just got my first class artifact for my Siren. On the skills/powers page, I notice it says it is level 1 in the description and the number 1 appears beside its icon. Does that simply denote the level of the item, like owning a level X required weapon, or is it something that can improve somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find higher level artifacts (up to a level of, I believe, 6) through gameplay as rare drops from enemies/chests. You will only keep the highest level drop of a given element (explosive, fire, corrosive, shock) per character. I'm not sure if there's any trick to finding artifacts as drops, they seem to occur like any other uncommon drop.

Comment: The element is the element type of the enemy you defeated to get it so if you're looking for a certain element, you should target specific elemented enemies. Also, many of them can be acquired through specific story missions during your playthroughs. http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Artifact

Answer (score 0):

None of the items you pick up can level up. Once you get them, they stay at that level. This also applies to Borderlands 2.